# Jenkins: confusion about ubuntu "jenkins" user and SSH Permission denied from gitlab

Tags: jenkins, ssh, gitlab

I am setting up Jenkins in my ubuntu server and trying to create a auto-build job. My plan is that in my local computer, after I do git push to master branch in the app repo, Jenkins in my ubuntu server will pull the latest master branch and start running the app.

I have set up Jenkins and configured with Gitlab with most steps successfully:

1. I have created a Personal Access Token in Gitlab and configured the Token in Jenkins server.
2. I have set up the auto-build job and selected `Build when a change is pushed to GitLab. GitLab webhook URL: http://35.222.111.55:8080/project/test`; I have created the Secret Token and configured Gitlab Repo with the webhook integration.
3. In Jenkins Auto-build job configuration, in the `Source Code Management` section, I have provided the gitlab repo url and the credential (SSH username with private key) so that jenkins can pull from the repo.

When I push to master branch in my local computer, Jenkins successfully starts the build. However, it gives the error at the step of `git pull` from the repo:

```
+ cd /home/John/jenkins_test/
+ git pull
git@code.myapp.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

This was because in point 3 above, the SSH private key I provided belongs to a default user. When Jenkins runs the build, it does things through a different user. I did some research and found:

1. Jenkins creates a `jenkins` user in ubuntu when it gets installed.
2. When Jenkins trys to build and execute the shell, e.g. the `git pull` step, it use the `jenkins` user to do so.

This means that when I set up the CI/CD with Jenkins and gitlab in ubuntu server, I need to:

1. `su - jenkins` to switch to the `jenkins` user and do `ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096` to create a SSH key pair for the user. Then save this SSH key in gitlab.
2. After I first `git clone my-repo` in the ubuntu server, I need to go into `my-repo/.git` and do `sudo chown -R jenkins .git/` to give `jenkins` user permissions to do `git pull`
3. For any other steps in the build, for example creating a directory or remove a file/directory, I need to manually go into the ubuntu server and give related permissions to the `jenkins` user first.

How come there is no official documentation regarding these steps?

Also, when I do `su - jenkins` to switch to the user, it asks for a password. How to find what password it gave to the user when creating this user in Jenkins installation???

All these seems to be over-complicated and I think I must had done something wrong here.
What am I missing?

Comment: Ragarding Jenkins password, You can look up to this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041125/default-jenkins-user-password