# Installing Jenkins the first time and do not know the default user name

Tags: jenkins, passwords

I tried using Jenkins or my admin username as `user` and `password`. For password, I tried to update using `sudo passwd jenkins`, so I am fine on that. However, I am skeptical about the user name. How do I confirm the username for Jenkins? Can someone pls help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the default Jenkins password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227305/what-is-the-default-jenkins-password)

Comment: no my question is i want to know my user name not password.

Answer (score 22):

During the initial run of Jenkins a security token is generated and printed in the console log. The username is `admin`

The token should look something like,

```
*************************************************************

Jenkins initial setup is required. A security token is required to proceed.
Please use the following security token to proceed to installation:

41d2b60b0e4cb5bf2025d33b21cb

*************************************************************
```

For me the initial admin password was in a log at `~/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

after installing with homebrew.

[source](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/getting-started/installing/#create-admin-user-and-password-for-jenkins)

Comment: Thanks! but I have installed via homebrew and I dont thnk I have come across the above. I tried with username admin and it still doesnt work.

Comment: I updated my answer with the location the log should be at when installed with homebrew.

Comment: Ah thats the problem I am facing. I am unable to find the intialAdminPassword in my secrets folder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568381/installed-jenkins-2-19-2-pkg-and-it-says-to-enter-initialadminpassword-from-the

Comment: I just noticed, there is a secret key which i just dragged and dropped into my browser and I got something like 51e84abf59589daf8f553dc2dca09559144ef08e648eb4724e5b19b04573efd2 but this doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: I got it resolved. I was trying to access through my admin account which i now realized that I have to login as the jenkins user. haha

Comment: Good Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 4):

If you pod is running in a Kubernetes cluster, just look at the running process … Your initial password will be shown…

e.g.

```
--argumentsRealm.passwd.admin=**3kJQtPDkhk** --argumentsRealm.roles.admin=admin
```

Answer (score 3):

**Username:** `admin`

For password,

```
cat /Users/$(whoami)/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

you will get similar to this token `2762710d8dab4c88a59fea0a2e559069`

Comment: If you are running a Docker Jenkins instalation, then you will need to get inside the container so you can retrieve that password with something like: `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash` and then search it in `var/jenkins_home` or wherever you have jenkins_home configured <3