# How to login in Jenkins first time?

Tags: macos, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed Jenkins by following the tutorial step wise step. It launched localhost and asking me for username and password. Most surprising thing is that there is no message or info that how to get this username and password. Even in all tutorial on internet has nothing written about this first time login screen. They all shown a dashboard screen with all options like manage users, manage security etc.

There is a clickable menu (Jenkins) on top left side of web page but it again loads login screen. Can anyone please tell me how to login in this screen. I am using mac machine. Even I tried http://localhost:8080/jenkins but it again loads login screen. So it is looking I can not access it without login but same time there is no way to create new user.

[image]

Comment: Check this ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570173/i-am-installing-jenkins-for-the-first-time-and-how-do-i-find-the-default-user-na