# Migrate jenkins users from old server to new

Tags: jenkins

We have a Jenkins server installed on the windows server, but planning to move Jenkins to ubuntu server. How can I migrate users to old Jenkins server to new server? 
Tried with copying config.xml, secrets, users folder to the new server, but not able to log in.

Comment: How do you Configure Global Security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy also the plugins or at least the plugin that you use for authentication purposes ([matrix based](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security), [LDAP](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin)). I have migrated data between Jenkins servers using [thinBackup](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/thinBackup) plugin. You should be able to login using the [initial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570173/i-am-installing-jenkins-for-the-first-time-and-how-do-i-find-the-default-user-na) Jenkins password.

```
sudo cat /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

I have written a [guide](https://qamag.net/setup-ubuntu-jenkins-master/) on the Jenkins setup in Ubuntu, it could help you.