# Jenkins issues in default credentials

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. While I am trying to install Jenkins in Linux in my laptop and deployed the jenkins.war in apache server and tried to start jenkins using homepage using url https://localhost:8080/jenkins , but it's asking for username and password, I have given admin and system generated password on apache server and all other admin/ admin also but nothing working.

Can anyone tell me the default username and password for Jenkins?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28906663/2484006 Does this answer help you?  Modified to match where you installed jenkins on your machine

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, i have forgot to mention this i am trying to install it in windows machine not in linux..can u please help me to guide me...

Comment: The jenkins installation itself shouldn't be very different.  One of the nice things about java.  So if you find your windows directory where jenkins is installed, those instructions may still help.  (The point there, is to find your jenkins install directory, and then open the config.xml file in a text editor, where you will be able to set your security setttings to let you in without a password)

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword. 
If jenkins home is different then /secrets/initialAdminPassword.