# Facing Issues with Jenkins Configuration

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and i am facing some issues.

Issue 1:
I am ***not getting any option to Create User*** in the Jenkins dashboard or any other Jenkins screen. I have downloaded the LTS version of Jenkins war file and deployed it on Tomcat server

Issue 2:
I create the admin user as part of Jenkins setup. I ***could not login the next time with this user***. Where does the Jenkins user credentials get saved ?

Issue 3:
How do i view Jenkins logs or debug the steps where Jenkins login wasnt successful ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the logs as detailed in [JENKINS Logging](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging): that should show you why the admin account is not working when you are using it the first time you want to log on.

For testing, you can [fiddle with the "useSecurity" testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28906663/6309) and restart Jenkins. (again, only for testing)

Answer (score 0):

Issue 2: you can check the jenkins logs and get the administrator token for default admin user.